# How to query an Array of Embedded Documents where at least two documents satisfy the query with a filter

Tags: mongodb

Given the example below, I'd like to query the _id that contains both documents ({x:30, y:40}{x:40, y:50} independently of "time"). But x and y need be filtered.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5caa04c6eef934095e66ebc5"),
        "position" : [
                {
                        "x" : 30,
                        "y" : 40,
                        "time" : ISODate("2019-03-28T14:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                        "x" : 40,
                        "y" : 50,
                        "time" : ISODate("2019-03-28T14:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                        "x" : 50,
                        "y" : 60,
                        "time" : ISODate("2019-03-28T14:00:00Z")
                }
        ]
}
```

For example (it doesn't works):

```
db.testes.find({position: {$all: [{x:{$gt:28,$lte:32}, y:{$gt:38,$lte:42}, time:{$gte: ISODate("2019-03-28T14:00:00Z")}}, {x:{$gt:38,$lte:42}, y:{$gt:48,$lte:52}, time: {$gte: ISODate("2019-03-28T14:00:00Z")}}]}})
```

or

```
db.testes.find({position: {$all: [{x:{$gt:28,$lte:32}, y:{$gt:38,$lte:42}}, {x:{$gt:38,$lte:42}, y:{$gt:48,$lte:52}}]}})
```

But this works:

```
db.testes.find({position: {$all: [{x:30, y:40, time:ISODate("2019-03-28T14:00:00Z")}, {x:40, y:50, time:ISODate("2019-03-28T14:00:00Z")}]}})
```

I appreciate for help

Comment: Could you please share your desired result.

Comment: I'd like to receive the object that has two or more matches in the position array.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
db.collection.find(
 {$and:[
 {$and:[{"position.x":{$eq:30}},{"position.y":{$eq:40}}]},
 {$and:[{"position.x":{$eq:40}},{"position.y":{$eq:50}}]}
 ]}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your subdocument array inside [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#restrictions) by [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) ([MongoDb aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)). Try as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            position: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$position",
                    as: "pos",
                    cond: {
                        $or: [
                            { $and: [ { $eq: [  "$$pos.x", 30 ] },  { $eq: [  "$$pos.y", 40 ] } ] },
                            { $and: [ { $eq: [  "$$pos.x", 40 ] },  { $eq: [  "$$pos.x", 50 ] } ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The result you will get as given below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5caa04c6eef934095e66ebc5"),
    "position" : [
        {
            "x" : 30,
            "y" : 40,
            "time" : ISODate("2019-03-28T19:30:00.000+05:30")
        }
    ]
}
```